# How to hide navigation tab using angular4 in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created 3 tabs in angular 4. Currently I am working on 2 of the tabs and I want to work on the 3rd tab in the futur.

I want to hide the 3rd tab using javascript/typescript.

app.component.html

```html
<div>
  <ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li class="tab" *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [class.tab--active]="tab.active">
      <label (click)="clickTab(tab)">{{ tab.name }}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <app-detail *ngIf="tabs[0].active" [app1]="app1"></app-detail>
    <app-detail1 *ngIf="tabs[1].active" [app1]="app1"></app-detail1>
    <app-detail2 *ngIf="tabs[2].active" [app1]="app1"></app-detail2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set `tabs[2].active = false` in your `AppComponent` constructor, or `ngOnInit`

```
export class ActiveTabsPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(values: any[]): any[] {
        return values.filter(val => val.active);
    }
}


<li class="tab" *ngFor="let tab of tabs | activeTabs" [class.tab--active]="tab.active">
```

Comment: That'll only hide the tab content, not the tab itself.

Comment: so sorry I missed, so u can write your Pipe, where you can filter only active tabs
for example

<li class="tab" *ngFor="let tab of tabs | activeTabs" [class.tab--active]="tab.active">

Comment: @samura Right... This looks so much easier than `display: none`... ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @JeremyThille this doesnt look easier but i just needed complex solution so choosed this one:)

Answer (score 1):

Why using Typescript? Use CSS.

```
ul.nav-tabs li:nth-child(3){
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to use javascript for that?

Comment: @samurabhati it is possible, see my answer. CSS, though, is much faster for things like this.

Comment: @samura why make difficult when you can make easy.... _why_ do you _absolutely_ want to use a script to simply hide a DOM element? This is just overkill

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li class="tab" *ngFor="let tab of tabs" *ngIf="!tab.hidden" [class.tab--active]="tab.active">
      <label (click)="clickTab(tab)">{{ tab.name }}</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <app-detail *ngIf="tabs[0].active" [app1]="app1"></app-detail>
    <app-detail1 *ngIf="tabs[1].active" [app1]="app1"></app-detail1>
    <app-detail2 *ngIf="tabs[2].active" [app1]="app1"></app-detail2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add a `hidden` field to your `tab` object you want to hide and set it to `true`.

Comment: What does your `tabs` object look like? It's an array, right? In the object in the array you want to hide, add `hidden: true`.